# How add audio in Jquery Mobile and play on android device (samsung galaxy)

Tags: jquery, mobile

can you give tutorial how to add audio player in jquery mobile and then packaging with Android SDK that can play on android device (samsung galaxy android 2.3)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this Youtube video help?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwK96UfQPWo

Also, I think you might want to use Backbone.js for a serious app. Take a look at this:
http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2011/08/building-the-soundcloud-mobile-site-using-backbone-js/

That's how Soundcloud Mobile was made. It's an awesome app!